# Laravel 9 make html table into a blade component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to make this simple table into a blade component. here is my code so far:

```
            <table class="table-fixed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User ID</th>
                        <th>Full name</th>
                        <th>Email address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($users as $user)
                        <x-user-row :user="$user" />
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

the component code (user-row.blade.php):

```
@props(['user'])
    <tr>
        <td"><a href="{{url('user', [$user->id]);}}">{{ $user->id}}</a></td>
        <td">{{ $user->name}}</td>
        <td">{{ $user->email}}</td>
    </tr>
```

and the output is this :

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxjMw.png)

I can't figure out why the data displays first before the table tag.
I am completely new to this Laravel framework.
Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are adding `"` inside td, please use this instead, and let me know:

```
<tr>
        <td><a href="{{url('user', [$user->id])}}">{{ $user->id}}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->email}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I didn't notice the " . Next time I'll check my code line by line :)